# Apache Tomcat + JSF + Primefaces: Ajax update cause fail on form

Tags: ubuntu, jsf-2, primefaces, tomcat7, netbeans-7

My environment is:
PrimeFaces: 3.1.1
Server: Apache Tomcat 7.0.34.0
JSF: Mojarra 2.2.0
JDK: 1.7.0_25
IDE: Netbeans 7.3.1
SO: Linux Ubuntu 13.04 64bits

I am having the following situation: 
There is in my xhtml a form with several components. One of this components is this below:

```
        <h:panelGrid columns="4" rendered="#{!inputControlador.tipoDocumentoPessoa()}">
            <p:autoComplete value="#{inputControlador.movimentacao.fornecedor}"
                            completeMethod="#{inputControlador.completaPjs}"
                            id="fornecedor"
                            rendered="#{!inputControlador.tipoDocumentoPessoa()}"
                            size="50"
                            var="pj"
                            itemLabel="#{pj}"
                            itemValue="#{pj.id}"
                            forceSelection="true"
                            converter="#{inputControlador.converterPJ}"                                                     
                            onkeydown="cleanCampos(this.id)">                                                    
                <p:ajax event="itemSelect" 
                        listener="#{inputControlador.primeiraCategoria}" 
                        update="@form"/>
            </p:autoComplete>
        ...
        </h:panelGrid>
```

When I choose a element in the autoComplete component the anothers autoCompletes in the form start to fail with this error:

```
        Set 11, 2013 7:00:38 PM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
        SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/privado/input/input/edita.xhtml]
        java.lang.NullPointerException
                at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.encodeSuggestionsAsList(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:366)
                at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.encodeSuggestions(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:313)
                at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.encodeResults(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:92)
                at org.primefaces.component.autocomplete.AutoCompleteRenderer.encodeEnd(AutoCompleteRenderer.java:74)
                at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:924)
                at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1863)
                at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl$PhaseAwareVisitCallback.visit(PartialViewContextImpl.java:559)
                at com.sun.faces.component.visit.PartialVisitContext.invokeVisitCallback(PartialVisitContext.java:183)
                at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1689)
                at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
                at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
                at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
                at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
                at javax.faces.component.UIForm.visitTree(UIForm.java:371)
                at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
                at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.visitTree(UIComponent.java:1700)
                at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processComponents(PartialViewContextImpl.java:399)
                at com.sun.faces.context.PartialViewContextImpl.processPartial(PartialViewContextImpl.java:319)
                at javax.faces.context.PartialViewContextWrapper.processPartial(PartialViewContextWrapper.java:219)
                at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.encodeChildren(UIViewRoot.java:1004)
                at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1856)
                at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:417)
                at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
                at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
                at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
                at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
                at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at br.com.clicksistemas.web.FiltroEntityManager.doFilter(FiltroEntityManager.java:73)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
                at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

        java.lang.IllegalStateException: CDATA tags may not nest
                at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlResponseWriter.startCDATA(HtmlResponseWriter.java:681)
                at javax.faces.context.ResponseWriterWrapper.startCDATA(ResponseWriterWrapper.java:179)
                at javax.faces.context.PartialResponseWriter.startError(PartialResponseWriter.java:341)
                at org.primefaces.context.PrimePartialResponseWriter.startError(PrimePartialResponseWriter.java:210)
                at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handlePartialResponseError(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:200)
                at com.sun.faces.context.AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.handle(AjaxExceptionHandlerImpl.java:124)
                at javax.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerWrapper.handle(ExceptionHandlerWrapper.java:100)
                at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:119)
                at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
                at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at br.com.clicksistemas.web.FiltroEntityManager.doFilter(FiltroEntityManager.java:73)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
                at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: getWriter() has already been called for this response
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.Response.getOutputStream(Response.java:605)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.getOutputStream(ResponseFacade.java:197)
                at br.com.clicksistemas.web.FiltroEntityManager.sendProcessingError(FiltroEntityManager.java:172)
                at br.com.clicksistemas.web.FiltroEntityManager.doFilter(FiltroEntityManager.java:113)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
                at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
                at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

The interesting (or not) about this is that the same code runs fine deploying at Windows in mostly cases, occuring rarely.

If instead of send a update for entirely form sent only for some components someones of its don't stay consitently. Don't show or hide, the values stay wrong.

It is a very weird behaviour and only occurs on this page, on this component.

Comment: Can be several thing. How did you set the javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD in web.xml? If this is server try client. Then you got a serializable problem. If not post all your backing beans so we can check if something is wrong there.

Comment: NullPointerException - this is big red light, and signal your error has nothing to do with ubuntu or netbeans. 
Check the PrimeFaces code in the given line, but at 90% "#{inputControlador.completaPjs}" returned null.